# Thyroid / cricoid movement in the Laryngeal Articulator Model

Tags: articulation

In a singing context, at least some voice training methods look to develop the ability to tilt the thyroid cartilage and (separately) the cricoid cartilage, as a way of changing tone and projection. For example, the Estill method teaches that the thyroid can be tilted forward by imagining you're about to make a whimpering sound.

On the other hand, Esling et al's Laryngeal Articulator Model does not seem to feature these movements. Unless I am missing something, the basic idea is that the larynx concertinas when raising of the thyroid combines with retraction of the tongue root and narrowing of the pharynx.

Does this mean that Esling et al. don't accept that the cartilages can be tilted (I'm fairly sure I can tilt the thyroid) or is the tilt subsumed in some other part of their model? I suppose there could be some other reason for leaving it out, but their overall approach does seem to be pretty comprehensive.

Comment: My interpretation of their model is that the "larynx" is bigger than traditionally thought. It's not that they deny that there is control over the intrinsic laryngeal muscles, it's that they needed to show that there are other things going on.

Comment: Thanks. I was fairly blind to that aspect of it because I never had much of an idea of what had traditionally been counted as part of the larynx. Anyway I have now got hold of the book itself. It will take some digesting... They undoubtedly acknowledge that there is control over some movements of the larynx, but their list of possible configurations doesn't match the Estill list in that there's no mention of tilt (or not so far) as an independent movement...

Comment: ... They go into a lot of detail listing the possible settings of the other articulators so I'm still a bit surprised they would leave this out. If the Estill trainers really are doing what they say they're are doing, it has quite a profound effect on voice quality.